# cs50 sql inserting data into a table

Tags: python, sql, cs50

```
import csv
from cs50 import SQL
db = SQL("sqlite:///roster.db")
with open ("students.csv" , "r") as file :
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    record = {}
    same = []
    for row in reader :
        n = db.execute("INSERT INTO houses(house_id , house)  VALUES (?, ?)", row['id'] , row['house'])
        a = db.execute("SELECT * from houses")
        print(a)
```

the program above keeps telling me some error messages that I do not really understand

[image]

I do not know how to fix that. I did try to put the variable `row['id']` directly to the value parenthesis, but I got a empty table with nothing in it.

That is the part when I ran ".schema" to get the table.
The table "name" is created in the command line argument with sqlite3 instead of running python code, is that why the error above mentioned about the "name" table?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE0KA.png)

Comment: ALSO in the case of doing VALUES ("row[id]", 'row[house]') , I need to use triple ' ' for the whole sentence (if not it always shows me that there is error in the program , which I also got confused)

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. I don't see where `main.name` is coming from.

Comment: Are you sure that's the whole code you are running?

Comment: I forget to mention I did have several tables , name is one of them. But I did not do anything with the name table yet in the python code beside I created and inserted some data in name while calling sqlite3  to CREATE TABLE and import some data in it( Which works perfect when I executing SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the second image is the schema (better to post as text not image!), there is a typo in the REFERENCES clauses of the house and head CREATE statements. Read them carefully and critically. It will not fail on the CREATE,  only when trying to insert into either of the tables.